# Resume parser in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jdom, .doc

I want to parse a resume to get different titles and content, which includes bullets, paragraphs, urls. I have the resume in .doc/.docx format. Research so far has resulted in

1.building an xml file from the .doc file and then
2. build an xml parser using JDOM.

Is there any other approach or a better way to do this? 
some algorithm that would help identify structures in resume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look like you are in right direction. 
Simple approach is  : 
Once you identify information and moved further, you just need to transverse based on +/- steps with calculated spaces, and identify results.

I am sure you are using NLP methodology which can help you to get data with proximity and then you can remove noise based on your experience.

or simple go and get some already build up.  I recomend you [RChilli CV Parsing](http://www.rchilli.com)  or others like hireability or sovren and discuss your need. I am sure you get some information

thanks
-K

Comment: I am now working with Apache POI which supports Word documents in Java. Its easier to work in that.

Comment: so you want to use apache tools ... this is perfect, but you need to bring lot of plugins like opennlp of apache .. use them  and you see you start getting data

Comment: I am now trying to implement functionality of opennpl.Thank you for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

Interesting -- I worked in a solution where we used Solr to identify my identities.

Another approach is - you can use Apache Solr / index document into that, and fetch faceted search .

Only challenge is how to build library. This will be much shorter and simpler than Apache POI

Let me know if you need some help ?

Comment: I am reading about solr but I don't quite understand how would it work. I run the start.jar and then indexed a csv file using post.jar but I am stuck from hereon. Also can you explain how could I import it to my existing java project? Thanks